# How do you manage perl modules on a Debian system?

Tags: linux, debian, perl

I'd like to know if you have a method for managing perl modules on your Debian system, with respect to the following:

1. Installing new modules
2. Listing of manually installed modules
3. Checking dependencies, and uninstalling modules

I have looked at this perlmonks article for background reading: [What is the best way to install CPAN modules on Debian?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=753416)

I have previously installed perl modules using the CPAN module. I have also used dh-make-perl in some cases, when following instructions to build other packages that had perl dependencies.

I'd like to institute a coherent policy on my machine so I can better manage how and where the modules are installed, and reduce the chance of breaking perl on my system. I would strongly like a system where I can detect and uninstall modules that are no longer being used.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398221/how-do-you-manage-perl-modules-on-linux

Comment: isn't superuser kind of end-user centric and isn't perl management a sysadmin or home-guy-learning-sysadmin stuff?

Comment: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `apt-get` and `dh-make-perl` for all packages, `deborphan --guess-perl` will find perl packages without any dependencies, which you can then remove and run it again iteratively. `deborphan` has a keep list which you can add the ones you're actively using to and they won't show up.

So to make this work, you'll have to uninstall all the modules you installed via CPAN and reinstall them with `dh-make-perl`. Manually installed modules can be detected by looking for "No available version in archive" in the ouptut of `apt-show-versions libsome-module-perl`.

Answer (score 5):

I use `apt-get` to install most modules.  If a module is not in one of the repository (or if I need a latter version of a module), I install that module into my home directory with `cpan`.  This is made easier by the [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) module.  Download the tarball from CPAN, decompress it, change directory into it, and then type

```
perl Makefile.pl --bootstrap
make
make test
```

If any of these steps fail, ask a question here.  If all of the steps succeed then type

```
make install
```

You will then need to add the following line to whatever profile file you use (e.g. `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc.):

```
eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)
```

Log out and log back in (run that command in the current terminal), and then type

```
cpan
```

It should ask you if you want to auto-configure CPAN, answer yes.  When it is done you should be able to install modules to a directory named `~/perl5` by saying

```
cpan Module::Name
```

The line you put in your profile sets up the `PERL5LIB` variable, so programs will be able to find the modules you installed.  It puts the `~/perl5` directory ahead of the system directories, so if you have version 1.0 of Foo installed via `apt-get` and version 2.0 of Foo installed via `CPAN`, the `CPAN` version will be loaded.

Comment: +1. This makes WAY more sense to me than running two completely separate perl instances/installs.

Answer (score 3):

Leave Debian's Perl alone and install a second Perl that you manage with cpan:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398221/how-do-you-manage-perl-modules-on-linux

Comment: I like this approach, but for one issue: Some modules I install are to satisfy dependencies in other packages that I'm aiming to build and install on my machine. If I install a second Perl, won't I have to jump through hoops to make these packages see and use the 2nd Perl at runtime, while system installed packages continue to use the original install?

Comment: No hoops at all.

Comment: ouch. especially if any of your perl stuff touches any debian stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the modules, I'm fairly sure you can use the apt-get command to install some of the more common modules.

apt-get install perl5-crypt (maybe its p5-crypt - its been a while).

It depends a lot on what modules are required though, many of them are not in the apt packages.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem for me because I now have a system where some modules have been installed via apt-get, some via dh-make-perl and still others via the CPAN module.